# Не работает нормально Page item

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

Начал изучать apex, и для начала использовал tutorial представляемые apex, там был один веб сайт Global Exchange в котором мы делали страничку с chart где выбирали страну и по ней менялся график. Вроде ничего сложно создать Page item выбрать select list выбрать SQL потом Dynamic action сделать change выбрать совой item, после в графике выбрать свой item через :item, Выбрать действия при Ture -> refresh выбрать свой регион, и все окей было пока делал Global Exchange, выбираешь страну, все меняется работает! Но как только стал делать свой маленький проект, сделал все теже самые шаги, но почему-то не работает Page item не создается и уходит в Session как это было в Global Exchange, и я ни как не могу понять почему.

А теперь об всем очень подробно, вот моя структура

[image: Структура]

Series 1

[image: Sql в графике]

SQL

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(detection_date, 'MON') AS month, COUNT(*) AS total_detections
FROM DETECTION
WHERE TO_CHAR(detection_date, 'YYYY') = :P1_YEAR
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(detection_date, 'MON')
ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(detection_date, 'MON'), 'MON') ASC;
```

Идем дальше создаем Page item

[image: Page item 1]

[image: Page item 2]

[image: Page item 3]

[image: Page item 4]

Для этого item мы имеем такой SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM detection_date)) AS display_value,
                TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM detection_date)) AS return_value
FROM DETECTION
ORDER BY display_value DESC;
```

Теперь делаем Dynamic Action

[image: Dynamic action]

После создаем True действие

[image: True action]

Вроде бы должно работать
НО

[image: Result]

Получили такую картину, значения она берет нормально! Все года есть, но при изменение, происходит refresh нашей диаграммы, но значения P1_YEAR не устанавливается в Session и ничего не происходит.

[image: Page item]

SQL Там и там работает нормально! Так-как если поменять вручную P1_YEAR то диаграмма берет нормально значения и показывает нужные данные, она почему-то просто не устанавливает значения в SESSION при изменение. Так-же и DEFAULT значения которое стоит 2021 так-же не попадает в SESSION, Почему я не знаю, вроде все сделал как надо, но что-то не так...